# Netbeans: Error parsing files - How to deal with?

Tags: php, netbeans

I get this very annoying "Containing files with errors." message on my project in Netbeans. There are errors to both js, php and css files. Is there any way to repair/ignore? I've tried to clear the Netbeans cache.

I recently switched from Vim to Netbeans.

[image: Netbeans file menu showing errors]

Answer (score 1):

To filter out CSS parsing errors,
Open CSS file that contains error and when you click on the error bulb(Which appears at the error line) you can see an option as 'filter out CSS parsing errors in 'yourprojectname''. Click it.

Comment: the line is not highlighted now but the file is still marked as "(!)error parsing file"

Answer (score 0):

I can see you have written 2 years ago and you got only one answer,  so I suppose either you solved your problem or simply you forget it. Anyway, today I had one similar yours and I solved by doing this: I pick with the left button of my mouse, over the Tea Cup at the side up-left on my tiny screen of projects, then I pick again but with the right button over the same place and a menu appears, I choosed: Clean and Build, and the errors flags disappeared, so I could run it. it's very important to clear, my codes had not lines errors before to do this. I hope it works for you and to the persons with similar problems visiting this place. Tchao!

Answer (score -1):

I tried this method and managed to solve the same problem on netbeans 8.0, open one of the Css files that has the error and from the solving error option choose filter out Css parsing errors in "your project name", I think its the third option.