# Un filtering previously filtered out hints or errors on NetBeans

Tags: netbeans

Once hints or errors are filtered out on NetBeans, how can it be undone?

NetBeans has the option to filter out hints and errors. Once filtered, how can it be undone? Where can I manage filtering rules?

Couldn't find any documentation.

Comment: First navigate to **Tools > Options > Editor > Hints**, and then select the relevant language from the _Language_ drop list within the _Options_ window. You can then check/uncheck checkboxes for the various types of hints as needed.

Comment: Thanks, @skomisa. If I understand correctly, these are global settings. What if I filtered out a hint only in a specific file? Where can I manage this?

Comment: Unfortunately you can't filter hints at the individual file level in NetBeans. See the answer I just posted.

Answer (score 0):

Hints can be included/excluded in NetBeans in two places:

- Globally, using **Tools > Options > Editor > Hints**, then selecting the relevant language from the *Language* drop list.
- At the project level, using **{project} > Properties > Hints**, then selecting the *Use project-specific options* option, and the relevant language from the *Language* drop list:

  [image: Project hints]

Notes:

- Global settings will apply to all projects, unless specifically overridden at the project level, as described above.
- There is no way to configure hints at the individual file level.

Comment: Thanks. I was referring to this option: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CyLom3Y5_4h2Ng3M7x0lMSorcRcAq_9r/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: @AsafMoshe [1] Your question specifically asked about a general issue with hints, but since you have a concern with a _specific error_ please update your question accordingly.  Include sample code so that others can reproduce your problem. [2] Have you tried clicking the light bulb icon that prefixes all the error messages? Doing that should display a menu offering options on actions you might want to take. [See this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46877701/2985643).

Comment: @AsafMoshe Also see this [old NetBeans bug report](https://bz.apache.org/netbeans/show_bug.cgi?id=240422) relating to the first message on your screen shot(_"Unexpected token AT_IDENT found"_). It states: _"special" characters like = or @ need to be escaped in CSS file_. Is that possibly relevant for your issue?

Comment: Thanks @skomisa. [1] I *don't* have a concern with a specific error, my question *is* general. The screenshot is just an example. These same options are available for every type of hint. [2] I'm not sure I understand this part. As my screenshot shows, I *did* click the light bulb - this is how I got the options to show up. My question isn't about filtering out, but about *undoing* filtering out. (For this reason, I also believe the answer you referenced isn't relevant).

Comment: Regarding the old NetBeans bug report - again it isn't relevant, as my question is general. My question is: Once a hint has been filtered out *for a specific file* - how can it be undone?

Comment: @AsafMoshe OK - we seem to be misunderstanding each other! I am still not understanding your specific concern. I'm not sure what else to add since (as stated in my answer) you can't filter _for a specific file_.

Comment: Thanks @skomisa. Have you seen the screenshot I shared with a link? It shows the option for filtering for a specific file, which *does* exist. The second option there, marked with a red arrow, is to filter out CSS parsing errors for that *specific file*. Maybe if we can pin point this essential fact we can understand each other better.

Comment: OK, I had missed that. My fault and now I understand your concern. I'll dig deeper. It would improve your question to provide some trivial sample code that triggers the issue.

Comment: Great. I'm glad we understand each other now :) Hopefully, you will find an answer. My research came up with nothing, but I'm relatively new to NetBeans.